# setting up environment variables in cmake script

Tags: cmake

setting up a single variable in cmake script is clear and easy.

but I need to perform this another way:

there is a number of *.cfg files which contain a lot of variable in format:

```
...
VAR_NAME="<VAR_VALUE>"
...
```

is there way (for cmake) to go throu such files and set up all variables from there?

Comment: `configure_file` command.